# Counting unique occurrences of values in a hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to count occurrences of unique values matching a regex pattern in a hash.

If there's three different values, multiple times, I want to know how much each value occurs.

This is the code I've developed to achieve that so far:

```
def trim(results)
  open = []

  results.map { |k, v| v }.each { |n| open << n.to_s.scan(/^closed/) }
  puts open.size
end
```

For some reason, it returns the length of all the values, not just the ones I tried a match on. I've also tried using `results.each_value`, to no avail.

Comment: Give us a sample input hash and the expected output please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way:

```
hash = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz', d: 'foo'}

hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(k,v),h| h[v]+=1 if v.start_with?('foo')} 
  #=> {"foo"=>2}
```

or

```
hash.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|(k,v),h| h[v]+=1 if v =~ /^foo|bar/} 
  #=> {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Thank you everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
hash = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz', d: 'foo'}
groups = hash.group_by{ |k, v| v[/(?:foo|bar)/] } 
# => {"foo"=>[[:a, "foo"], [:d, "foo"]],
#     "bar"=>[[:b, "bar"]],
#     nil=>[[:c, "baz"]]}
```

Notice that there is a `nil` key, which means the regex didn't match anything. We can get rid of it because we (probably) don't care. Or maybe you do care, in which case, don't get rid of it.

```
groups.delete(nil)
```

This counts the number of matching "hits":

```
groups.map{ |k, v| [k, v.size] }
# => [["foo", 2], ["bar", 1]]
```

[`group_by`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) is a magical method and well worthy of learning.

Answer (score 1):

```
 def count(hash, pattern)
   hash.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), counts| 
     counts[k] = v.count{|s| s.to_s =~ pattern}
   end
 end

 h = { a: ['open', 'closed'], b: ['closed'] }
 count(h, /^closed/)
 => {:a=>1, :b=>1}
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: My reading of the question coincides with @theTinMan's, but it's not very clear.

Comment: Yeah, OP was calling #each on the value. Hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

I think it worths to update for `RUBY_VERSION #=> "2.7.0"` which introduces [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally):

```
h = {a: 'foo', b: 'bar', c: 'baz', d: 'foo'}
h.values.tally #=> {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1, "baz"=>1}
h.values.tally.select{ |k, _| k=~ /^foo|bar/ } #=> {"foo"=>2, "bar"=>1}
```